# jquery ajax error: "206 Partial Content"

Tags: jquery, json

Im trying to do this

`$.getJSON('http://lix.hisvux.se/~johanb/json.js', function(data) { ...`

But im getting "206 Partial Content" in firebug. Does it have something to do with mame origin policy? Do i need to keep both files on the same server? Or whats the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually yes, you do have to keep files on the same server. Do you have a link or more details?

Comment: Ok. A link to what? The link to my test object is posted above, and im running the script from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Both files need to be on the same server. The only (san/fe) workaround is to use JSONP. If you control the server that should be easy, but if you do not you could use online converters to do the trick, e.g. http://campeaux.com/2011/03/json-to-jsonp-bridge/